# How to make login with social network account or other website ?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jsp, jquery

How to make user account with other website.such as [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login)
If user have social network account they can log-in to site else they must sign-up web site. Please give me sample or idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get API from the social network site for log in and signup functionality using their social network account. Some of the social network developer links for developer manuals.
Facebook
http://developers.facebook.com/

Twitter:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/open-source-examples

http://hayageek.com/login-with-twitter/